# Spark in-memory cache for metadata & block locations

Tags: apache-spark, hive, spark-jobserver

In sake of Spark low latency jobs, Spark Job Server provides a [Persistent Context option](https://objectpartners.com/2017/03/07/spark-job-server-for-persistent-contexts-and-low-latency-jobs/). But I'm not sure, *does persistent context contains metadata, block locations & any other information required for query planning?*. By default Spark should read this information from Hive Metastore (disk IO/network).

*Does Spark has any option for keeping in-memory all information necessary for query planning?*